# EC2 Instance | Amazon web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I need to purchase EC2 with DEDICATED quad Xeon CPU @2.5Ghz or higher, with 8 GB of RAM on Amazon web service (AWS). Please could could you let me know which Ec2 instance should I select?

Should I go for "Window on m1.xlarge Dedicated" option? Please guide

Comment: Only the very largest instances have dedicated CPUs. In all other cases, they are shared between multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.ec2instances.info/

The **M1 Extra Large** looks like what you want, since you can only choose 7GB or 15GB.  As far as I know, Amazon doesn't publish which sizes are dedicated vs not, and the sharing could change in the future. Under Linux, there is a CPU measurement called "steal time" that will tell you when your CPU was busy with other tasks outside your VM. Windows should have a similar performance counter.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provide [dedicated tenancy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html) on hardware level.

It also include an [extra fee].

Only the new instance type have some infromation on the type of CPU used.

In any case you will have some performance impact from the hipervisor.  You will need to run several test in order to be sure you meet the expected perfomance.